# Nav bar position changes

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to fix a problem with my nav bar on my website. If I move from the home page to the gallery page, the nav bar changes slightly (the navigation links move up by 2 pixels), and the bar seems to shift to the right, though I'm not sure why. The same happens when you move from the gallery page to the about page, only it doesn't shift to the right.

the URL is [www.peach-designs.com](http://www.peach-designs.com). The code is really too big to post, but perhaps somebody could help me by looking using Firebug or Web Developer tool.

Comment: [Congratulations: it's still not centered properly.](http://i.imgur.com/ZeOGf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also change the class id wrapper in **index.php**
this will make index page to be same as the other pages

```
enter code here

#wrapper {
   margin: auto;
   width: 990px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't a very good solution, because the the navigation isn't precisely centered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want the navigation on each page to be in the same place it is on your home page (it's properly centered on that page). Also, I've only tested in Firefox (because you suggested using Firebug), where your site seems to work - in Chrome there are no images.

First, remove this from `galleryStyle.css`:

```
#wrapper {
    height: 599px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 990px;
}
```

Then do this on `gallery.html`, `news.html`, `about.html`, and `contact.php`:

Move `<div id="main">` to outside and before `<div id="wrapper">`, so it ends up like this:

[image]

Doing this centres your white overlay properly. At the moment, it's a bit too far to the right.

Comment: yes, this is a problem I've been having in chrome, if you scroll down when it loads in chrome, you can see the navigation fine, but for some reason the main image doesn't appear. If you click 'home' on the navigation, it loads up fine. Not sure what this problem could be though.

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper div on your gallery page is narrower than your home page (only 990px). Because it's occupying less space and being centered, your nav div is nudging to the right on the gallery page to occupy the smaller space of its parent div (wrapper) than the wider space of the home page. Try using consistent sizes and you'll run into these problems less.

Comment: No problem, hope it was useful.